# Problemas al borrar un registro rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

tengo una aplicacion que posee los siguientes modelos hasta ahora:
 - Post
 - User
 - Comment
 - Information

El problema que estoy enfrentando es que modifica la columna de la tabla users para permitir que un usuario pueda ser admin. hasta alli todo perfecto, pero cuando hago la validacion en graph y hago las pertinentes pruebas cuando se borra un post a traves del servicio, este no solo borra el registro hijo(post) si no que tambien borra el padre(usuario relacionado a este post). A continuacion adjunto los modelos.

**Post:**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :comments
end
```

**User:**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password

  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
  has_one :information

   validates :name, presence: true
   validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness:true
 end
```

La mutacion para la eliminacion del post es la siguiente:

```
class Mutations::DeletePost < Mutations::BaseMutation
argument :id, ID, required: true

type Types::PostType

def resolve(id: nil)
    user = context[:current_user]
    return Errors unless user

    post_id = Post.find(id)
    return Errors unless post_id

    if user && (user.id === post_id.user_id || user.is_admin == true)
        post_id.destroy
        return { post_id: post_id }
    else
        puts 'Not allowed to delete'
    end
end

end
```

Comment: Elimina `dependent: :destroy` en `belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy`; i.e. `belongs_to :user` es suficiente.

Comment: @Gerry, gracias estimado ha funcionado.